# Sort Files By Name Before Looping

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a script to automatically apply Windows Update files. I want to be able to apply them in a specific order, so I named them in the format #_FILENAME (ex: 1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b50173cd3362785fe102a6e5977956b.msu)

A standard loop through the directory won't apply them in order. I tested the following, but it doesn't sort the files correctly by name:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "PATH HERE" -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*msu*"} | 
Sort-Object -Property Name | ForEach-Object{ 
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

This would output something like this (which is not correct):

> 1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b50173cd3362785fe102a6e5977956b.msu
> 10_windows10.0-kb4570332-x86_88c4f7cce6237f42e24f07df1553e116b68400cb.msu
> 11_windows10.0-kb4577667-x86_1c6cc1cc8410f13a73bfe42e2d46c3a5434e53b3.msu
> 12_windows10.0-kb4577668-x86_38fd259988991bebc10d1ae38eb86cdc7d260f25.msu
> 13_windows10.0-kb4587735-x86_f67a582db752d5f01628ea5a71bd61b260f01eac.msu
> 14_windows10.0-kb4586793-x86_055782f642b3d5f52d5bb41f0fd21d2695a61881.msu
> 15_windows10.0-kb4594442-x86_c0131d2aa4753f40a9cedccef78a1fb9d3d5b7c1.msu
> 16_windows10.0-kb4592440-x86_3b7ee00f35ee72cf098e745199b9d34040855482.msu
> 17_windows10.0-kb4598230-x86_54c413174df931928c180e53a2d43f19dab00da2.msu
> 18_windows10.0-kb4598480-x86_cf41f4aad0b9fd35f922849d4e3d1f5587e09d2f.msu
> 19_windows10.0-kb4601345-x86_b4eb5e67d0b0325a79a8097623eab6b4eb7c5563.msu
> 2_windows10.0-kb4541331-x86_2add69875b760d19358a4dbd88a8b974ab7c36a6.msu
> 20_windows10.0-kb4601393-x86_3afe5b8330a10a49a01649a04459797194b3a057.msu
> 21_windows10.0-kb4577586-x86_947f151a8bb5a0b0797702e53431c52d56c02c32.msu
> 22_windows10.0-kb5000859-x86_f9156ae9cf5ae5daad986cb0f984d0872cb09055.msu
> 23_windows10.0-kb5000822-x86_6a9695aa4566b0edc63c25e0c0472f30b19efee0.msu
> 24_windows10.0-kb5001568-x86_ac43cdb614bfc2b4692ab2503efddc041a5b0c02.msu
> 25_windows10.0-kb5001638-x86_9bda1241132ff712a47d9d16cf0d978eec200a53.msu
> 26_windows10.0-kb5001404-x86_1ea8389ee96eff8140e22ed380c18843feb6090a.msu
> 27_windows10.0-kb5001342-x86_93e0b1c91098bb41afe81a7424a65b323be67cde.msu
> 28_windows10.0-kb5001407-x86_19a2574b1f0debc7d1587fc0c3f99d86f6864476.msu
> 29_windows10.0-kb5003243-x86_d291d08679c83237bc807fe45b0cc6e1370c61f1.msu
> 3_windows10.0-kb4554354-x86_2777d98ded121ce72a2e0c95ce274f60a7ad15e9.msu
> 30_windows10.0-kb5003171-x86_abffc1521d18a4fbf9d5aed15f75ea4094965f31.msu
> 31_windows10.0-kb5003711-x86_70a7ef9f67506eaeac5ae1747e90220e04e22492.msu
> 4_windows10.0-kb4549947-x86_76883e8e6c1f79903eb2a4d7c5781bc36c898242.msu
> 5_windows10.0-kb4550969-x86_f4ea0594e950dbeaa11af4252db2019e71131fb2.msu
> 6_windows10.0-kb4562562-x86_d1dc34578ef2e2dae2ff77f17bce5a4f51a20667.msu
> 7_windows10.0-kb4567513-x86_70baf70eb117086008b4b88cfc04ff73acfa6ad4.msu
> 8_windows10.0-kb4558997-x86_2adfc6fe55a1d1aad32eee373a629684b9aac292.msu
> 9_windows10.0-kb4566424-x86_2b9807df71713c5c4d09d85d80df682334f57e1f.msu

How can I get this to sort the files properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "PATH HERE" -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*msu*"} | 
Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name.Split('_')[0]} | ForEach-Object{ 
    Write-Host $_.Name
}
```

- Split on underscore `_` and get the first element of the array:

```
'1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b.....msu'.split('_')[0]
```

This would get the number `1` and `[int]` to convert it to `integer` from `string` which then can be sorted.

---

### Edit:

I think it's important to mention why [Abraham's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68180113/sort-files-by-name-before-looping/68180351#comment120500511_68180351) approach using **`-as`** might be better than casting the object type.

Using the same example as before. If we attempt to sort by the first `integer` before the underscore, casting `[int]` will work just fine, and it works well for OP too because he was certain of the naming convention of the files (all file names could be splitted by `underscore` and the first item of the splitted array would always be a number). However if we are **NOT** sure if all items could be converted to `int` we should use `-as` to avoid terminating errors.

#### Example:

```
PS /> @'
3_windows10.0-kb4554354-x86_2777d98ded121ce72a2e0c95ce274f60a7ad15e9.msu
1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b50173cd3362785fe102a6e5977956b.msu
2_windows10.0-kb4541331-x86_2add69875b760d19358a4dbd88a8b974ab7c36a6.msu
asd_windows10.0-kb5003243-x86_d291d08679c83237bc807fe45b0cc6e1370c61f1.msu
4_windows10.0-kb4549947-x86_76883e8e6c1f79903eb2a4d7c5781bc36c898242.msu
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Sort-Object {[int]$_.Split('_')[0]}
```

Would yield:

```
Sort-Object : Cannot convert value "asd" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:7 char:21
+ '@ -split '\r?\n' | Sort-Object {[int]$_.Split('_')[0]}
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (asd_windows10.0...6e1370c61f1.msu:PSObject) [Sort-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionEvaluation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjectCommand
```

But with `-as` we wouldn't have any terminating error:

```
PS /> @'
3_windows10.0-kb4554354-x86_2777d98ded121ce72a2e0c95ce274f60a7ad15e9.msu
1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b50173cd3362785fe102a6e5977956b.msu
2_windows10.0-kb4541331-x86_2add69875b760d19358a4dbd88a8b974ab7c36a6.msu
asd_windows10.0-kb5003243-x86_d291d08679c83237bc807fe45b0cc6e1370c61f1.msu
4_windows10.0-kb4549947-x86_76883e8e6c1f79903eb2a4d7c5781bc36c898242.msu
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Sort-Object {$_.Split('_')[0] -as [int]}
```

**Yields:**

```
asd_windows10.0-kb5003243-x86_d291d08679c83237bc807fe45b0cc6e1370c61f1.msu
1_windows10.0-kb4539571-x86_f63a97438b50173cd3362785fe102a6e5977956b.msu
2_windows10.0-kb4541331-x86_2add69875b760d19358a4dbd88a8b974ab7c36a6.msu
3_windows10.0-kb4554354-x86_2777d98ded121ce72a2e0c95ce274f60a7ad15e9.msu
4_windows10.0-kb4549947-x86_76883e8e6c1f79903eb2a4d7c5781bc36c898242.msu
```

Comment: Beat me to it! `$_.Name.Split('_')[0] -as [int]`, I like your approach tho, using it as a *type literal*; well casting it.

Comment: This works, thanks! One small fix: `[int]$_.Split('_')[0]` needs to be changed to `[int]$_.Name.Split('_')[0]`

Comment: @Daniel woops, my bad, I edited the answer. Glad it worked :)

Comment: @Daniel I think you should check the last edit, you might learn something new. Thanks to Abraham for pointing that out.